# Django CMS Custom Plugin doesn't render the template

Tags: django-cms

Running a fresh install of django-cms 2.4.0-RC1, django 1.5.1 and python 2.7. I'm trying to create a very simple custom plugin with a single field. The plugin registers in the admin and works fine. It successfully stores in the database. It's just not rendered in my template.

I have verified the render_template path and also tried using a hardcoded absolute path. I have tried overriding the render method in CMSSelectDegreeLevelPlugin.

Am I overlooking something obvious? I've made very similar plugins before (in different versions of django-cms) and had no trouble.

**models.py:**

```
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from django.db import models


class SelectDegreeLevel(CMSPlugin):
    degree_level = models.CharField('Degree Level', max_length=50)
```

**cms-plugins.py**

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from models import SelectDegreeLevel


class CMSSelectDegreeLevelPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = SelectDegreeLevel
    name = _('Degree Level')
    render_template = "cms/plugins/select_degree_level.html"

plugin_pool.register_plugin(CMSSelectDegreeLevelPlugin)
```

**select_degree_level.html**

```
<h1>static text test {{ instance.degree_level }}</h1>
```

Comment: Are you get it to work...?

Comment: I was building me this in my own fresh Django cms installation. and it works. Can you show somewhere you project?

Comment: Do you already try the stable 2.4 version of Django Cms?

Answer (score 0):

I think you field is not in the context. I do it normally over this way. Add this function to you CMSSelectDegreeLevelPlugin Class

```
# Way to decide what comes in the context
def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        extra_context = {
            'degree_level': instance. degree_level,
        }
        context.update(extra_context)
        return context

# Simplest Way
def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
    context['instance'] = instance
    return context
```

[Also you can read more here in docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0.rc1/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html#storing-configuration)

Comment: I eventually got frustrated and dropped to django-cms 2.3.6 and it worked after adding a render method. However, even with a render method, it didn't work in 2.4.0-RC1. Also note, the [render method isn't required](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html#the-simplest-plugin) in 2.4.0 for simple plugins.

Comment: Great that I was helping you with 2.3.6. Yeah, I saw this also now that the render method default is to add instance and placeholder to it.